# What are good venues for publishing original mathematical research in monograph form?

Tags: journals

Of course, it's very easy to find journals which publish original mathematical work, and there are a number of book series that publish expository monographs.  But if you have a work of original research which has reached monograph length, I don't know of many options.  The only ones I know which are reasonably prestigious are [Memoirs of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/publications/ebooks/memoirs) and [Asterisque](http://smf4.emath.fr/en/Publications/Asterisque/Presentation/).  Are there other good options for publishing such work I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Community Wiki?

Comment: Doesn't proceedings of steklov institute allow long papers?  You could also write a book.

Comment: I hoped for a moment that Todd was suggesting that community wiki MathOverflow answers are an appropriate way of disseminating your mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

The European Math Society publishes [EMS Monographs in Mathematics](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/emsmonoseries.html).  There's also the Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics, not to mention [The Annals of Math Studies](http://press.princeton.edu/math/series/amh.html). These all fit in the rubric of `reasonably prestigious'.  I think International Press publishes research monographs ([at least they used to](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/books/items/00000072/index.html)!)

Answer (score 3):

Progress in Mathematics ([web](http://www.springer.com/series/4848)) sometimes publishes research monographs.